# the operation about rdd and reducebykey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I create a rdd like this:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A:0.740:8, B:0.242:5, C:0.145:2"),
  ("A:0.232:8, C:0.14:7, D:0.164:5, E:0.34:2, F:0.37:1"),
  ("B:0.245:13, H:0.123:4, I:0.673:2")
))
```

if I want to reduce by the key and sum the last two elements. Then get the results like:

```
"A:##:##"
"B:##:##"
"C:##:##"
...
```

What should I code?

Comment: So what is our output in this case ?

Comment: String.I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need, 
First, `flatten` all the data  split with `":"` and get the first index as a key and use `reduceByKey` to calculate sum

```
  rdd.flatMap(_.split(",")).map(x => {
    val s = x.split(":")
    (s(0).trim, (s(1).toDouble, s(2).toInt))
  })
    .reduceByKey((x, y) => ((x._1 + y._1), (x._2 + y._2)))
    .map(r => (r._1 + ":" + r._2._1 + ":" + r._2._2))

 .toDF().show()
```

Or convert to `Dataframe` and `concat` it later, which will make it clear to understand and easy

```
rdd.flatMap(_.split(",")).map(x => {
    val s = x.split(":")
    (s(0).trim, s(1).toDouble, s(2).toInt)
  }).toDF("a", "b", "c")
    .groupBy("a").agg(sum("b").as("sumB"), sum("c").as("sumC"))
    .select(concat_ws(":", Seq($"a", $"sumB", $"sumC"): _*).as("value"))
    .toDF().show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------+
|value                  |
+-----------------------+
|H:0.246:8              |
|A:0.972:16             |
|I:0.673:2              |
|B:0.487:18             |
|C:0.28500000000000003:9|
|D:0.164:5              |
|E:0.34:2               |
|F:0.37:1               |
+-----------------------+
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: If i want to use groupby and map.How to code this?Thx!

Comment: what you need to do after group by ? so that you are trying to use map?